# Toggle button for my google extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, popup

[image: error on chrome]

I am trying make the "XD" button in my pop up toggle on and off for my chrome extension, however, I keep getting error shown in the screen shot... I tried everything to let my main.js file to read the html but they don't seem to be talking to each other. Help would be appreciated thanks!

popup.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Work HARDER! </h1>
        <h2>-Tate</h2>
        <button id = "XD" class="button">Quitter Button</button>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
// toggle button 

const toggleButton = document.getElementById("XD");

let isTurnedOn = true;

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let extensionId = 'mgojbplmbhbcnefhbhoohphmppigjdco';
    if (isTurnedOn){
        chrome.management.setEnabled(extensionId, false, function() {
            console.log('Extension disabled.');
        });
        isTurnedOn = false;
    } else {
        chrome.management.setEnabled(extensionId, true, function() {
            console.log('Extension enabled.');
        });
        isTurnedOn = true;
    }
    
});
```

manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version" : 3,
"name" : "Focus" ,
"version" : "1.0" ,
"icons": {
    "16": "icons/favicon-16x16.png",
    "36": "icons/favicon-32x32.png",
    "48": "icons/andrew.png",
    "128": "icons/andrew.png"
},
"description" : "Focus by Tate.",
"content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches" : ["https://www.youtube.com/*", "https://signup.leagueoflegends.com/en-us/signup/redownload/*"],
        "js" : ["jquery-3.6.4.min.js", "./main.js"],
        "css": ["index.css"]
    }
],
"action" : {
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "icons/favicon-16x16.png",
        "36": "icons/favicon-32x32.png"
    },
    "default_popup" : "popup.html",
    "default_title" : "A simple popup"
}
```

}

tried to add src = "main.js" did not work...

tried making sure my id is correct in toggleButton and both are "XD"

tried document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ..... did not work thinking maybe we need to wait for button to load or smth

Comment: You should post your `manifest.json`.

Comment: Where's the screenshot?

Comment: Put old error messages in the Trash.
And you need  `"permissions": ["management"]` in your `manifest.json`.

Comment: Got it.

I put in permissions but still without luck:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Context
popup.html
Stack Trace
main.js:21 (anonymous function)

Comment: Why are you injecting main.js into the webpage with a content script?
I think you need to study extensions before posting here.